# user to user push notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I have seen many questions on here and online that address this topic, but they all are from a long time ago, and are possibly outdated. I wanted to get a more recent answer if Firebase has implemented anything recently that is capable of a user to user push notification system, essentially what is used in all chat applications, or if the best option is still currently using Onesignal.

Comment: See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! These days, you can use Cloud Functions for Firebase to do things like send a notification when something interesting happens on the Database side of things.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications) where a user gets notified via notifications when they gain a new follower. Obviously, your part of the database portion will probably change depending on what exactly you want to trigger a notification, but the general theory is the same.

[image: Flowchart of the DB -> Functions -> FCM flow]