# sending a push notifiacion by on click button firebase

Tags: android, firebase, button, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possiable to set an on click button which will send a  push notifiacion message to a user on fierbase? I seccssed sending a push message by the website but I really need the option to send messages from the app.

Thankds!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [user to user push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790537/user-to-user-push-notifications)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it now with Functions. This means it is perceived as if were done by the app, but it is a longer way.

For start, there is no such a thing as an app to app Firebase Cloud Message, is very confusing because the Firebase Database is real time.

What was done before Functions, was to make the app trigger something on a server, and then the server will make FCM send the push notification.

Now with Functions, you don't need a server. Functions can listen to changes in the Firebase Database (also can listen to user creation) and can send Firebase Cloud Messages. So the complete flow is this:

1. The app will trigger a change in the database
2. Functions will be
   listening to that node
3. When the changed has listened, then a push
   notification will be triggered
4. If it is needed, Functions can
   request data from other nodes, to get the device token by example

This is the Functions documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Currently, Functions is in beta so, please see the samples here https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples

And here is a personal sample, which is heavily commented to clarify all the problems which I went https://github.com/cutiko/testing-functions

Good luck

Comment: thanks!
so is there a chance to do it on andriod studio? I am really confusied

Comment: Your app is created in Android Studio, Functions is written in Javascript, so you can do it in any editor, including Android Studio. This 8 minutes video should put you on track to use Functions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ

Can you please mark this as correct if you consider it so?